# Как написать компактней регулярное выражение?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Написал регулярное выражение, которое пропускает определённые года рождения в тексте. А есть более компактный способ? `re.search(r'[2000-2023]')` не работает. А так как-то громоздко

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Regex Numeric Range Generator](https://3widgets.com/)

Comment: классно)) спасибо)

Comment: `20[01]\d|202[0-3]`

Comment: Или не использовать так регулярки: 1) у вас там дата, распарсите ее через datetime и проверьте год как число, типа `2000 <= year <= 2023` (или `year in range(2000, 2023 + 1)`) 2) или вытащите тот же год регуляркой как `\d{4}`, приведите к числу и аналогично 1) проверьте как число :)

Answer (score 1):

Хоть генератор и делает короткое регулярное выражение для диапазона чисел:

```
(200[0-9]|201[0-9]|202[0-3])
```

В данном случае его можно сделать еще немного компактнее:

```
20([01][0-9]|2[0-3])
```